# Multi site and media uploader

Tags: multisite, uploads, media, permissions

There seems to be a strange issue with my multisite on my live blog. Maybe its because I have one site set to "deleted" - so I can edit it, but the public can't see it?

My current upload is set up as such:

`wp-content/blogs.dir/10/files`

This gives me a link such as (the link is real, I replaced my site address with example.com):

`http://example.com/files/2013/01/Screenshot-from-2013-01-04-141248-300x150.png`

This works on every single site I have, I recently created a new site and uploading images via the uploaded shows me a broken image and the console states it cannot find it.

So I went to FPT and went into blogs.dir (stored at the base of wp-content) and went to site 10 and sure enough, under `files/2013/03/` are the files I have uploaded.

I then went to my media uploader, looked at the broke image and clicked view, this showed me that the image was going from `example.com/files/2013/03/` - this is simmilar to all the other sites I have on the network, they all map images like this and the images work.

My next suspicion was file permissions, I checked the permission of "10" folder, it was not same as the rest so I did `sudo chown -R user-name 10` which changed the owner from apache to me.

Still the images get uploaded yet they are "broken" as in they cannot be found.

So I come to you guys to ask, **what's going on?**

Comment: Right-click on one of the "broken" images, copy the image's URL, and paste that URL into a new tab.  Does the image come up?  Does the URL look remotely right?  Is it a local URL?  (Also, I note that the example.com URL is looking for a file in `/files/2013/01/` but you then talk about `/files/2013/03/` -- make sure you're looking in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the fact that, at least for me, sites can not be "deleted." once I changed the status of the site the images showed up and started working as they should.